# Loading SWF over HTTPS

Tags: https, flash

We are currently trying to embed a swf into our page using https. That is to say:

```
swfobject.embedSWF("https://our.c.d.n.com/path/to/the/swf/File.swf", "altContent", "760", "630", "10.0.0", "swf/expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);
```

When we do this over https, however, we are finding that the main SWF file is having trouble loading some of its content. We are suspicious that it is a a matter of including a crossdomain.xml file but the crossdomain.xml file we have in our main directory that is pointing to our CDN does not seem to be automatically used. Is there more of a process involved as it pertains to swf over https? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem. The issue was that the xml file that was telling the swf where to look for was using a non https url.